# Is it possible to get the arXiv ID of all papers being referenced by a specific arXiv paper?

Tags: webservices, citation-management, resourceobject

I ran the below code and obtained a paper `article001` with arXiv ID `1609.05206v3`.

```
arXiv = ServiceConnect["ArXiv"] 
articles = arXiv["Search", {"Query" -> "Quantum Eraser", MaxItems -> 4}]
article001 = articles[[1, {"ID", "URL", "Published", "Title"}]]
```

Is it possible to get all the papers (say their arXiv ID) being cited by `article001`?

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is that there is no unique style for organising the bibliography on an arxiv submission, so you should write a code to parse that info from the pdf.  If you are lucky, the authors might have submitted the latex source as well and the task might be slightly easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `"ID"`  to construct a URL to link to the references page on `ui.adsabs.harvard.edu`:

```
refsLink = Hyperlink["https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/#abs/arXiv:" <> 
     First[StringSplit[#, "v"]] <> "/references"] &;

ds1 = articles[All, {"ID", "Title"}];
ds2 = articles[All, Key["ID"] /* <|"References" -> refsLink|>];

Join[ds1, ds2, 2]
```

[image]